# Symfony2 Render Form in Controller

Tags: forms, symfony

How do I render a form in a controller (not in a template)?  I'm looking for something like:

```
$form = $this->createForm(...
$output = $form->render();
```

$output would be the html for the form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The form is merely an object, it doesn't know what it's layout is supposed to be --- that's what the template is for. If you're in a controller extending from the default controller, you can get the HTML of a rendered template like so: `$html = $this->renderView('YourAppBundle:Blah:form.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView() ) );` where that template contains the form markup/rendering code.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing but thought there might be another way.  Thanks!